# Custom List items Different Colors?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, custom-list

I created a SP2013 page that has 3 different list-views of the same list. They're all set to Default Style and for some reason two of the Titles of the items are green when all of the rest are black. Any idea what's going on?

It does not appear to be a visited flag as I've visited others and they're still black. 
[image: Example of what I'm seeing attached]

I'm looking for them to be consistently black, or consistently green as to not draw attention to any unless I need to.

On a related note: I'm primarily a OOB but am interested in any feedback on being able to change the title of each list item to be a larger or bolded, or different color to make the hyperlink title stand out.

Comment: Is there any custom code added on page or any JSLink added to the list view?

Comment: No, no code on this page.

Comment: Try inspecting it using browser's developer tools, is there any custom css applied to it?

Comment: By default, the column value's color should be black. Does this issue occur for one view or three views? Does this issue occur on default list view page? How did you create "Item Title" column? If it is calculated column, check if there is HTML code in the formula. Also, you can use F12 to debug this issue.